# How to clean up v-bind directives from html code in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Ok, I've got some Vue code and HTML.

For example:

```
Vue.component('area-selectors-box', {
  template: `
    <div class="area-selectors-box">
      <area-selector v-for="(select, index) in selects" :select="select" :key="index"></area-selector>
    </div>
  `,
  props:['selects']
});
```

And in my page:

```
<div is="area-selectors-box" v-bind:selects="selects"></div>
```

It all works, but if I read the page source, I see the `v-bind:selects="selects"` portion, which is not standard compliant, I guess.

Similarly, other components have other object properties like:

```
Vue.component('area-option', {
  template: `<option :area="area" :value="area.term_id">{{area.name}}<slot></slot></option>`
  ,props: ['area']
});
```

which on the page source evaluates to something like:

```
<option area="[object Object]" value="82">Europa</option>
```

which is obviously not desirable.

How do I bind these properties without them appearing in the DOM as attributes?

Comment: _" which is not standard compliant, I guess"_  what makes you think that? What _"standard"_ are you applying that logic to? The only _issue_ I'm seeing here is that `area` it not suitable for binding into your `<option>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer is: pass props when you call the component, not in the component itself. This code will work and produce clean html:

In-page HTML:

```
<!-- pass selects to area-selectors-box -->
<div is="area-selectors-box" :selects="selects"></div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('area-selectors-box', { // pass select to area-selector
  template: `
    <div class="area-selectors-box">
      <area-selector v-for="(select, index) in selects" :select="select" :key="index"></area-selector> 
    </div>
  `,
  props:['selects']
});

Vue.component('area-selector', { // pass area to area-option
  template: `
    <select @change="selected" >
      <option disabled selected value="">Seleziona continente</option>
      <area-option v-for="area in select.areas" :area="area" :key="area.term_id"></area-option>
    </select>
  `
  ,props:['select']
});

Vue.component('area-option', { // pass nothing
  template: `<option :value="area.term_id">{{area.name}}<slot></slot></option>`
  ,props: ['area']
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, when `v-bind` encounters a binding name that isn't associated to a property on the target, the value is converted to a string and assigned as an attribute. Since `<option>` has no property named `area`, the object is assigned as a string attribute, which you observed in the DOM.

You can use [`v-bind`'s `.prop` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) to always assign it as a property:

```html
<option :area.prop="area" ...>
```

```js
Vue.component('area-selectors-box', {
  template: `
    <div class="area-selectors-box">
      <area-selector v-for="(select, index) in selects" :select="select" :key="index"></area-selector>
    </div>
  `,
  props:['selects']
});

Vue.component('area-selector', {
  template: `<div>
    <select v-model="selection">
      <area-option
         v-for="option in select.options"
         :key="option.id"
         :area="option.area" />
    </select>
    <pre>{{selection}}</pre>
</div>`,
  props: ['select'],
  data() {
    return {
      selection: null,
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('area-option', {
  template: `<option :area.prop="area" :value="area.term_id">{{area.name}}<slot></slot></option>`
  ,props: ['area']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    selects: [
      { id: 1, options: [
                { id: 10, area: { term_id: 100, name: 'Europe' } },
                { id: 11, area: { term_id: 101, name: 'Asia' } },
              ]
      },
      { id: 2, options: [
                { id: 20, area: { term_id: 200, name: 'North America' } },
                { id: 21, area: { term_id: 201, name: 'South America' } },
              ]
      },
    ]
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>

<div id="app">
  <area-selectors-box :selects="selects"></area-selectors-box>
</div>
```